# Make an array class using dictionaries only

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a student who is new to python. I am trying to define an array class below which uses a dictionary as its only member variable. I am assuming that Python implements dictionaries as the only structured type (i.e., there is no array, list, tuple, etc.).

I am facing difficulty in coding such a program.

This is my code:

```
class array(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dic={}

    def __init__(self,diction):
        self.dic = {}
        for x in diction:
            self.dic.append(x)

    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        self.dic[key]=value

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        if key not in self.dic.keys():
            raise KeyError
        return self.dic[key]
```

I want the program to work this way:

```
a = array('a','b','c')  #------output------

print(a)    # ['a', 'b', 'c']

print(a[1]) # b

a[1] = 'bee'

print(a)    # ['a', 'bee', 'c']

a[3] = 'day'

print(a)    # ['a', 'bee', 'c', 'day']

print(a[6]) # IndexError exception
```

Any suggestions, advice. :)

Comment: Why do you have 2 __init__functions?

Comment: Python does not support overloading in the sense of multiple constructors, so only one `__init__` (the second) will be used. Use default arguments instead

Comment: I would also recommend you don't call your class array - you're going to collide with the python data structure of the same name. Call it MyArray or something instead.

Comment: @DanielleM. I was just trying different ways of making the work program, like I said /i am noob in python here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with your class definition:

- `array` is already a data structure: better to rename using the proper Python class-naming conventions (`MyClass`).
- You cannot overload function definitions: better to use an unpacking operator (`*`) to extract all (if any) arguments.
- You cannot append to a dictionary: you need to assign to a key.
- Your call to `print` will display a generic class name, since you don't specify a `__str__` magic method. Since a `dict` is unordered, I did some funny business here to make it display as sorted, though I'm sure there's a better way.
- No need to raise a `KeyError` in `__getitem__`, since this will be raised anyway.
- Finally, I corrected your spacing.

Note that I've only implemented the methods necessary to make your test cases work.

```
class MyArray(object):
    def __init__(self, *diction):
        self.dic = {}
        for i, x in enumerate(diction):
            self.dic[i] = x

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.dic[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.dic[key]

    def __str__(self):
        return str([self.dic[i] for i in sorted(self.dic.keys())])
```